# Exiting KODI makes TV turn off

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, kodi, pi-zero, screen

I have two Raspberry Pis. One of them is a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian, and the other is a Raspberry Pi zero running Retropie. They both have KODI installed and on both of them whenever i exit, it turns off my TV. Then i have to press the power button on the TV to turn it back on. I have searched Google, YouTube and Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange and have not been able to fix it.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kodi implements [Consumer Electronics Control (CEC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control), which sends control signals between the Pi and the TV. It's pretty handy on the whole, allowing you to shuttle around menus using your infrared TV remote, and switch the TV on by tapping a menu key on a remote app like [Yatse](http://yatse.tv/redmine/projects/yatse). You can take a look over the docs on Kodi's wiki page [here](http://kodi.wiki/view/CEC).

The exact feature set varies a little between TVs, and it sounds like yours is responding (as it should be) to a CEC request from Kodi to shut down. You can turn that feature off by going through the menus to:

```
System -> Settings -> System -> Input Devices -> Peripherals -> CEC adapter
```

Once you've selected your CEC adapter you should have a page of options which includes `Devices to power off during shutdown` with an up-down control next to it. Flick through the options to 'None', then confirm with `OK` and try shutting down.

Comment: Before reading this simple answer I was trying to figure how to add a "switch off" event to the keymap or use cec-client to control Kodi—all of which is simply unnecessary. Thanks!

Comment: After upgrading to Kodi v19 ("Matrix") this setting was resetted to "TV" - so my TV was shut down too after switching off Kodi/Libreelec/Raspberry Pi. Changed this setting back to "None" and everything works fine again.